# $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1 ,$ then $ab + bc + ca$ gives =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a recent examination this question has been asked, which says:

$a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$ , then  $ab + bc + ca$ gives = ?

What should be the answer? I have tried the formula for $(a+b+c)^2$, but gets varying answer like $0$ or $0.25$, on assigning different values to variables.

*How to approach such question?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just knowing that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ is not enough to determine the value of $ab+bc+ca$. For example, if $a=b=0$ and $c=1$, then $ab+bc+ca = 0$. On the other hand, if $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, then $ab+bc+ca = 1$. In fact, using $$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ca),$$ you get that $$ab+bc+ca=\frac{(a+b+c)^2 - 1}{2}.$$

Comment: @Mathematician171 Yeah, thanks, I had a typo.

Comment: @avDec25. Why you changed $ab+bc+ca$ to $a+b+c$?

Comment: @Mathematician171 I did the opposite!!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on $a+b+c$:
$$
(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=1\\
ab+bc+ca=\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2-1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=1+2(ab+bc+ca)$
therefore $$(ab+bc+ca)=((a+b+c)^2-1)/2$$ so the value is not fixed

Comment: You just rewrote my answer.

Comment: i was writing d answer when u submitted urs

Comment: @Mathematician171 Or, he was writing the answer at the same time you wrote yours.

Comment: @Mathematician171 Similarly, I wrote the same thing as you in my answer, as I was editing my answer while you wrote yours.

Answer (score 1):

With this information the best you can do is the following
$$ab+bc+ac\leq1$$
which is a direct result of the AM-GM inequality i.e.
$$a^2+b^2\geq2ab$$
$$b^2+c^2\geq2bc$$
$$a^2+c^2\geq2ac$$
Summing sides respectively
$$1=a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ac$$

Comment: That is the best you can do in determining the upper bound, yes. However, a lower bound also exists.

Comment: Of course there is a lower bound for the given expression, but with the information in hand I do not think we could do much about the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 
(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)
$$

The LHS of the above identity is a perfect square, hence it is always positive or 0.

Thus,
$$
a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca) ≥ 0
$$

It is given that $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 =1 $ .
$$
1 + 2(ab + bc + ca) ≥ 0
$$
Therefore,
$$
ab + bc + ca ≥ -1/2
$$
It is possible to determine the upper bound of the above expression by applying the AM-GM inequality as follows: (as already done by [Arian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/172588/arian))
$$
a^2+b^2≥2ab\\
b^2+c^2≥2bc\\
a^2+c^2≥2ac
$$

Adding the above three inequalities, we get
$$
a^2 + b^2 +c^2  ≥ ab + bc + ca
$$
which implies
$$
ab + bc + ca ≤ 1
$$

Thus, the value of $ab + bc + ca$ lies in the interval $[-1/2, 1]$ .

Note: It is not possible to find an exact value for this expression, as already noted by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answers should be in terms of a,b,c

(a+b+c-1)(a+b+c+1)/2